# wordpress copyright dynamic

Tags: urls

Hi everyone I have a question how can you create a dynamic copyright in WordPress with URL that goes back to the home page as well as a URL that goes to the designer of the theme

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to look for the current copyright text inside your theme's `footer.php` file and substitute it with something more of your liking.

My suggestion, as I don't know what you mean for "dynamic", is to substitute the current text with a function call, like `<?php my_copyright_text() ?>`, and then define that function in your theme's `function.php` file in which you do whatever you need to do.

```php
function my_copyright_text(){

  $year = date("Y",time());
  $company = "Mycompany.com";
  echo "© 2018-$year $company"; //this is effectively HTML code
}
```

As the output of the function is HTML code you can insert tags and css classes as you like. For example `"© 2018-$year <span class="company">Mycompany.com</span>"`.

**It is strongly suggested to [use a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)**, as not to let theme updates overwrite your tweaks.

If you feel brave you can put some of the parameters in the theme customizer, [take a look here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/).

Comment: Okay would also like to have the beginning of year ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: such as 2018 - current year would like to make css adjustments

Comment: Yes, I know but this copyright 2018 - 2019 company and designer url

would like to make css adjustments

Comment: yes, I didn't understand, I made some edits in the answer

Comment: Okay I want a copyright starting year - current year and then link of the company and link of the designer of the theme further I would also like to be able to adapt with css like color padding margin font

Comment: the `echo` in my functions outputs HTML code, so you can edit it and put inside it whatever tags, css classes, text, etc. you like!

Comment: Okay thanks further have another question how can I make a navigation with title?

Comment: I suggest you ask another full question, using more detail in your requests :)

Comment: As we are in the comment section of an unrelated answer, so it is very difficult to answer properly your question. Please ask a "real" stackexchange question, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), so everyone can see and answer it.

Comment: Great! :) I see you are new here, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I thanked you for your reply, can you just do that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

below code Update Copyright Year in a Website Dynamically

```
&copy; 2018 – <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="#url">YourSite.com</a>
```

Comment: Okay but would have liked the beginning year and end year
not only end year / current year

Comment: I thanked you for your reply, you can also add the author and url from the author

Answer (score 0):

> **First you can put below code in your theme's functions.php file.**

```
<?php
function copyright_text(){
    $previous_year = date('Y') - 1;
    $current_year = date('Y');
    $company_url = esc_url(home_url('/'));
    $designer_url = 'http://www.designer-url.com';
    echo '<div>&copy; copyright '.$previous_year.' - '.$current_year.'<a href='.$company_url.' class="comp"> company </a> and <a href='.$designer_url.' class="desg" taret="_blank"> designer </a></div>';
}
?>
```

**And Second you can use this code** `<?php echo copyright_text(); ?>` **where you want to display copyright in footer like your theme's footer.php file.**

***Hope this code may help you. I have tested this code and it's working fine.***

Comment: Thanks for the code that is what I was looking for

Comment: @tmmcursist Thank you for this. please mark (tick) as green mark of my answer so it can help for someone which is finding like this.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you use Tanmay without wordpress please?

Comment: @tmmcursist for which purpose you want to code with wordpress so I can clearly understand.